# What do I do with this pipe/well that is flooding the front yard?

Tags: plumbing, water, well

I   recently moved into my house and found this in the front yard which was disguised as a birdbath.

After winter, I took a step near the "birdbath" only for my foot to sink 8 inches in the mud caused by a constant flow coming from the pipe.

I used an old pool hose to temporarily redirect the water flow onto the driveway and it has been flowing for over a week straight now.

If anyone has any ideas on **what I can do** or who I can call I would appreciate it.

[image] it!

Comment: Bottled Artesian Well Water. Mmmm.  It was not disclosed on the home inspection report? Is the previous home owner available to speak with?

Comment: Will need to contact local well drilling company.  If well not used anymore will need to be sealed off to prevent stuff from getting to the water table.  Quite sure previous owners should have done this.

Comment: That is one of the nastier looking ones probably artesian I have seen. The plus is you probably will never run out of water if you are on on a normal well.   If on city water get a shallow well pump and use your water for irrigation saving $ and not putting chlorinated water on your lawn. @crip659 plugging an artisan well can cause ground movement problems including having the well “spring up” under the house. In many areas these are just natural springs. I don’t think they require disclosure unless within the foundation area but since there is a casing it is probably recorded by the county.+

Comment: Is there a retention pond by the front yard? It could be an old observation well, but it is intriguing that you have drained so much water.

Comment: is that a corrugated drain pipe behind the pool pipe?

Comment: If so, does it work?

Comment: @Jasen it is, but not entirely sure where it drains to. Considering it was making the surrounding area almost like a swamp, I can't imagine it was going anywhere but back into the ground? Not sure.

Comment: I'd count that as a "does not work satisfacturally"  I thought that perhaps the water was not flowing into the pipe. or perhaps it was not a pipe.